# Permission to use my calendar in Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, calendar, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add an event to my Calendar in my android app I made in Xamarin. But I keep getting the error "requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR or android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" . Can someone please help me with this? Here is my code.....
Thank you!!!

```
    using System;
    using MyApp;
    using MyApp.Droid;

    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Provider;
    using Xamarin.Forms;


    [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (CalendarManager))]

    namespace MyApp.Droid
    {
        public class CalendarManager : ICalendarManager
        {
            public CalendarManager () {}

            //public const string WRITE_CALENDAR = "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR";
            //public const string READ_CALENDAR = "android.permission.READ_CALENDAR";


            //android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

            public void SaveEvent(DateTime start, DateTime end, string title, string notes, string location, bool allday) 
            {

                ContentValues eventDetails = new ContentValues();

                eventDetails.Put (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, start.ToUniversalTime ().ToString ()); 
                eventDetails.Put (CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, end.ToUniversalTime ().ToString ()); 
                eventDetails.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, title);
                eventDetails.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation, location);
                eventDetails.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllDay, allday);


            eventDetails.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "UTC");
            eventDetails.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "UTC");

            var ctx = Forms.Context;
            ctx.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/permissions/), you have to declare which permissions your app requires, so that Android can notify the user when they install the app.

Setting the Read Calendar and Write Calendar permissions should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You  can explicitly add the permission tag for the calendar APIs in your application's "AndroidManifest.xml" file inside the `<manifest>` tag as :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```